# ACF fields or repeater fields not saving value to user taxonomy term

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

Hi I have the following taxonomy:

```
register_taxonomy('user_position', 'user', array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'public'      =>true,
    'single_value' => false,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'labels'      =>array(
        'name'                        =>'User Category',
        'singular_name'               =>'User Category',
        'menu_name'                   =>'User Categories',
        'search_items'                =>'Search User Categories',
        'popular_items'               =>'Popular User Categories',
        'all_items'                   =>'All User Categories',
        'edit_item'                   =>'Edit User Categories',
        'update_item'               =>'Update User Category',
        'add_new_item'                =>'Add New User Category',
        'new_item_name'               =>'New User Category Name',
        'separate_items_with_commas'=>'Separate professions with commas',
        'add_or_remove_items'     =>'Add or remove professions',
        'choose_from_most_used'       =>'Choose from the most popular professions',
    ),
    'rewrite'     =>array(
        'with_front'              =>true,
        'slug'                        =>'user-category',
    ),
    'capabilities'    => array(
        'manage_terms'                =>'manage_options',
        'edit_terms'              =>'manage_options',
        'delete_terms'                =>'manage_options',
        'assign_terms'                =>'read',
    ),
));
```

I also have a ACF repeater field called documents, which I have assigned to the user_position term, the ACF field is adding to the user category taxonomy, however the data isn't being saved when I go to add a field, once i press the blue button add document, nothing gets saved.

I have tried changing assign_terms to 'edit_posts' but that didn't help, I have looked on the ACF forums and came across some topics saying the field names maybe to long so I have shortened them but still no luck.

Can anyone help me with this or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is user a custom post type? This may be conflicting with the internal "user" data type.

Comment: No, I haven't made 'user' a custom post type.